# comparing the date in my excel file with system date

Tags: r, dataframe, readxl

I have an excel file which has two columns `start_date` and `end_date`. I want to compare the `end_date` with the system date but everytime I use this code I get an error:

> Incompatible methods ("ops.Date", "Ops.POSIXt") for "<"

I am reading excel file using

```
x<-read_excel("book.xlxs", Header="TRUE")
```

And now I am using

```
Myframe<-ifelse(x$end_date>Sys.Date())
```

What to do now?

Comment: Please, revise your code. There are many syntactical errors.

Comment: Try `Myframe<-ifelse(x$end_date>as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), 'TRUE_VAL', 'FALSE_VAL')`. `Sys.Date` does not return a `POSIXct` object; so you will need to coerce it into one.

Comment: Or maybe you want `Myframe <- x$end_date > Sys.Date()`. But these will only work if `class(x$end_date)` is `Date` - you'll probably need to do that conversion.

Comment: This i think worked but Can you tell me please what this does as I am new to r

Comment: Also, the first one you wrote that gives an output logical (0) . what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that you are trying to compare two objects of different classes. The call to `Sys.Date` returns an object of class `Date`. You can check that by calling `class(Sys.Date)`. This returns `Date`. Moreover, it looks like you are using the `readxl` package, which usually imports `datetime` columns as `POSIXct` objects. As a result, you are trying to compare `POSIXct` objects with `Date` objects. This will almost always cause errors. As recommend in the comments, you should either convert `Sys.Date` to a `POSIXct` object with the function `as.POSIXct` or you can convert the values in the column `end_date` to `Date` objects. I recommend you do the first because you're only converting one value with the following line of code:

```
Myframe<-ifelse(x$end_date > as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), 'TRUE_VAL', 'FALSE_VAL')
```

If no value in the `end_date` is greater than `as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())`, the comparison `x$end_date > as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())` will return an empty vector. That's why you are seeing `logical(0)`. This means that it is an R vector of `logical` values. But since it is empty, R will return `logical(0)`.

If you changed the comparison to `x$end_date <= as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())`, you may see a vector of `logical` values (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).

Furthermore, if you're looking to have a new column that tracks which rows in the column `end_date` passed the comparison test, you can do the following:

```
x$end_date_passed <- ifelse(x$end_date > as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), 'yes', 'no')
```

The new column here is called `end_date_passed`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But when I see the output of Myframe it gives me logical(0) . what does that mean?

Comment: But some dates in end_date are greater than current date!

Comment: Also when I am using <= it still shows logical(0) . what can be wrong ?

Comment: Another question I want to ask you is that how to update a column say for example end_date_passed having values yes or no with new values according to the comparison between end_date and sys_date?

Comment: @Suraj please the edits. If you have any additional questions, please create a new post. This question is already answered. Please considered marking it answered with the check mark next to it.